# The 'updateOne' method does not work. In the 'if' statement it returns in error - Angular , Mongo

Tags: angular, mongodb

The **updateOne** method does not work. In the **if** statement it returns in error:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const connection = (closure) => {
 return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean', (err, client) => {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
     let db = client.db('mean');
     closure(db);
 });
};

let response = {
 status: 200,
 data: [],
 message: null
};

const api = require('./server/routes/api');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

app.put("/api/product/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.log('app.put ');
      var updateDoc = req.body;
      delete updateDoc._id;
      console.log(updateDoc);
      connection((db) => {

          db.collection('product').updateOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) }, updateDoc, (err, doc) => {
            console.log('app.put');
            if (err) {
                console.log('app.put error: ');
                console.log(err);

            } else {
                console.log('app.put ok');
                updateDoc._id = req.params.id;
                res.status(200).json(updateDoc);
            }
          });
      });
    });

const port = process.env.PORT || '3000'; 
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on localhost:${port}`));
```

in the console displays such an error:

```
path_to_the_project_directory>node server
Running on localhost:3000
app.put
{ name: 'testzzz' }
app.put
app.put error:
{ MongoError: the update operation document must contain atomic operators.
    at Function.MongoError.create (path_to_the_project_directory\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:45:10)
    at toError (path_to_the_project_directory\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:149:22)
    at checkForAtomicOperators (path_to_the_project_directory\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:848:12)
    at Collection.updateOne (path_to_the_project_directory\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:822:13)
    at connection (path_to_the_project_directory\server.js:74:30)
    at MongoClient.connect (path_to_the_project_directory\server.js:18:6)
    at args.push (path_to_the_project_directory\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:404:72)
    at path_to_the_project_directory\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:255:5
    at connectCallback (path_to_the_project_directory\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:933:5)
    at path_to_the_project_directory\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:794:11
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'the update operation document must contain atomic operators.',
  driver: true }
```

What is the reason for the error?
I do not know what's wrong with the **updateOne** method. I added wrong parameters in the **updateOne** method?

The data in the **Mongo** database does not edit.

Comment: I think the problem might be in the second parameter of the`updateOne`, try changing `updateDoc` with `{ $set: updateDoc }`.

Comment: there is no mistake when I insert :
 var updateDoc = req.body; 
.updateOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params._id) },{ $set: updateDoc } , (err, doc) => { 

but it does not edit data in the Mongo database

Comment: Let me see if I understand, Do you take my recomendation?? Do you update your code to `{ $set: updateDoc }` and that solve the `the update operation document must contain atomic operators` error??

Comment: works, the error was in: {_id: new ObjectID (req.params.id)} and updateDoc._id = req.params.id;

Comment: Sorry @user2129896, but your comments are not very clear. I'm not sure if you solve your problem or not. Let me know if you need more help :).